# Зачем запускать отдельный сервер laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php7, laravel-8

Зачем для разработки `Laravel` приложения необходимо запускать сервер командой:

`php artisan serve`

Можно ли этого не делать, если, например у меня уже установлена связка `LAMP` на моем сервере?

Зачем мне поднимать еще один сервер при помощи вышеуказанной команды?

Почему нельзя разрабатывать без запуска сервера, как, например в `Yii2`?

Comment: предположу что для отладки у тех, у кого нет lamp

Comment: почему нелья? Можно. Можно и в докере запускать, и еще куча вариантов как можно. То как один из вариантов

Comment: Можно как хотите, это обычных PHP фреймворк. Хоть свой сервер разработайте. Встроенный сервер нужен для локальной разработки (в продакшене крайне не рекомендуют использовать).

Comment: Только учтите, что Вам необходимо будет настроить перенаправление на папку /public/. Многие новички теряются на старте. То есть, если Вы заходите на локальный домен и видите перечень папок и файлов, то Ваш сайт правильно отобразиться, если добавить  /public/ .Хотя изменением пути проблему не решить